# How to project a parametric curve to a free-form parametric surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, parametric

I need to project a parametric curve $\vec{r(t)} = (r_x(t), r_y(t), c)$, where $c$ is constant, into a free-form parametric surface $\vec{S(u,v)} = (S_x(u,v), S_y(u,v), S_z(u,v))$. However I did not find a way to do it.

Ideally, the solution should be analytical, but a numerical solution is acceptable as well.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Can you please say more about what you mean by _project_? Do you mean an orthogonal coordinate projection? Radial projection from the origin, or from some axis...?

Comment: When I say _project_ I mean an **orthogonal coordinate projection**, in the direction of the z-axis. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! The issue is to solve $S_x(u,v) = r_x(t)$ and $S_y(u,v) = r_y(t)$ simultaneously for $(u, v)$ as a function of $t$. In general that's hard (amounting to inverting a mapping from the plane to the plane), but for special classes of surface you might get nice analytic formulas. Are you doing this generally, or do you have special surfaces in mind?

Comment: I am trying a general procedure. But my initial application is for Bézier surfaces. An analytical procedure would be amazing, but a numerical approach to solve it would be really helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

A numerical approach using [Newton-Raphson method](https://observablehq.com/@fil/2d-newton-raphson):

For a fixed point of the curve corresponding to the value $t=t_0$, let us define:

$$\begin{cases}f(u,v)&:=&S_x(u,v)-r_x(t_0)\\g(u,v)&:=&S_y(u,v)-r_y(t_0)\end{cases}$$

The recurrent vector sequence

$$\binom{u_{n+1}}{v_{n+1}}=\binom{u_{n}}{v_{n}}-\begin{pmatrix}\partial S_x/\partial u&\partial S_x/\partial v \\ \partial S_y/\partial u&\partial S_y/\partial v\end{pmatrix}^{\color{red}{-1}}\binom{f(u_n,v_n)}{g(u_n,v_n)}$$

will converge (under the condition to be in a suitable vicinity of the solution) to a solution $\binom{u_{*}}{v_{*}}$, i.e., values of parameters $u$ and $v$ such that

$$\begin{cases}f(u_{*},v_{*})&=&0\\g(u_{*},v_{*})&=&0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}S_x(u_{*},v_{*})&=&r_x(t_0)\\S_y(u_{*},v_{*})&=&r_y(t_0).\end{cases}$$

Remark: the value of the $z$ coordinate is of course $z(u_{*},v_{*})$.